# Resolution of differential equation

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

All functions verify the condition below :

$$f''(x)+f(-x)=x+\cos(x)$$

I have to use something related to differential equations.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Any real function can be written in a unique way as the sum of an even function and an odd function, say
$$f=g+h$$
where $g$ is even and $h$ is odd.  It is easy to check that $g''$ is also even and $h''$ is also odd.  So we have
$$g''(x)+h''(x)+g(x)-h(x)=x+\cos x\ .$$
Equating even and odd parts,
$$g''(x)+g(x)=\cos x\ ,\qquad h''(x)-h(x)=x\ .$$
Solving by standard methods,
$$g(x)=A\cos x+B\sin x+\tfrac12x\sin x\ ,\qquad h(x)=C\cosh x+D\sinh x-x\ .$$
But $g$ is even so $B=0$, and $h$ is odd so $C=0$.  Hence
$$f(x)=g(x)+h(x)=A\cos x+D\sinh x+\tfrac12x\sin x-x\ .$$

Comment: This is for the help....I think that is correct say thank you in another form.

Answer (score 2):

Iterating the equation you get $f^{(4)}(x)-f(x)=x-2\cos \, x$ which can be solved by standard methods. Solutions of $\lambda^{4}-1=0$ are $\pm 1, \pm i$, so the general solution to $f^{(4)}(x)-f(x)=0$ is $ae^{x}+be^{-x}+c\cos \, x +d\sin \,x$. You will have to solve the inhomogeneous equation and go back to the original DE to see which of these are actually solutions. I hope you can fill in the details.

Comment: This introduces extra solutions which are not solutions of the given equation.

Comment: You get $f^{IV}(x)+f''(-x)=-\cos(x)$ and $f''(-x)+f(x)=-x+\cos(x)$, therefore $$f^{IV}(x)-f(x)=x-2\cos(x),$$ which is different from what you state.

Comment: @LutzL You are right. I have revised my answer.